# How can I preserve line breaks in a string when using web.py to generate HTML from a template?

Tags: python, html, templates, python-2.7, web.py

I'm using web.py to generate HTML pages using templates.

The HTML template is like this:

```
$def with (scene)

...

<p id="descriptions">
    $scene.descriptions[scene.status]
</p>
```

Some of the strings I want it to put there from the descriptions file include line breaks like this:

```
example_scene = (
"""Status 1 - Line 1
Status 1 - Line 2
Status 1 - Line 3""",
"""Status 2 - Line 1
Status 2 - Line 2
Status 2 - Line 3""",
)
```

But when it generates the HTML page, those lines are run together like this:

> Status 1 - Line 1Status 1 - Line 2Status 1 - Line 3

Rather than like this:

> Status 1 - Line 1
>
> Status 1 - Line 2
>
> Status 1 - Line 3

If I include a `\n` for a Python newline it has no effect, and if I include a `<br />` for an HTML newline it simply includes those characters like this:

> Status 1 - Line 1<br />Status 1 - Line 2<br />Status 1 - Line 3

Is there any way to preserve those line breaks??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web.py is [escaping the HTML](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor#filtering). To turn it off, change your template code:

```
$:scene.descriptions[scene.status]
 ^-- add this thing
```